# How can I control ads frequency?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityads

This question was already asked a while ago, and I wanted to check the present situation:

- Can I control ads frequency from the **dashboard**? (e.g. frequency capping in Admob)
- Can I control ads frequency through **Unity IAP API?**
- Is there are some **assets / services** that provide such functionality?
- If not, does that mean that I need to implement all that **"frequency control"** functionality manually?

Answer (score 0):

Ads Frequency is set manually, bec the app doesnt run ads without control, u tell the app when to show the ads, either you set a timer like show an ad every 1 min "only work if there is an ad available on your network" , or by button press...etc